# Linq To Sql - Get week day name from date

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Is it possible to construct a query in which I can retrieve week day name from a date into a separate column or variable?

I know I can very easily do this on .NET side but would like it to be in the query.

Comment: Can I ask why you want it to be in the query? What culture would you want to use?

Comment: I have a table of work shifts which saves each record by week day name, so Monday, Tuesday etc. Each record have a start time and end time against it eg: 9am to 5pm. I need to work out what work was carried out within shift hours.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use SqlFunctions...

```
var results=context.Listings
  .Select(l=>System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions.DateName("dw",l.modify_date));
```

Of course, this only works when using a SQL Server.  Methods that are cross-database, would be to use EntityFunctions.DateDiff with a known date to get the number of days between whatever and a known prior sunday, then modulus 7, then convert to a string.

Comment: I have added a reference to `System.Data.Entity` but it's still complaining that `'SqlServer' is not a member of 'Entity'`

Comment: Sorry, if you are using Linq to Sql, try `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.DateName`.  It's pretty similar to System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions which is for Entity Framework.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Is it possible to get this value based on Culture?

Comment: @YusrilMaulidanRaji Probably not, nor would I really recommend you return a day of week from the database as the OP wants.  I would recommend you return the actual date/datetime from the database in your controller (or DAL), and then format it as you want in your view.  In your controller,  `var results = context.Listings.Select(l=>l.modify_date)` and then in your view, `loopvariable.ToString("dddd")`.  The `.ToString("dddd")` will use the current thread Culture, or you can pass in a different culture as the second parameter if you need to override it.

Comment: The above assumes you are doing an MVC application.  For console/desktop/services, then use your best judgement on where/how to separate the data layers from the presentation layer.  WebAPI/RestAPI type applications shouldn't be sending back data in a specific culture at all.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible you will need to build your query which returns day names and then join to your result on day number

```
int[] dayNum={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

var result = from d in dayNum
    let dayOfWeek= (d == 1 ? "Monday" :
            d==2 ? "Tuesday" :
            d==3 ? "Wednesday" :
            d==4 ? "Thursday" :
            d==5 ? "Friday" :
            d==6 ? "Saturday" :
            d==7 ? "Sunday":"")
   let dn = d
 group d by new {dayOfWeek, dn} into dw
 select new { dw.Key.dayOfWeek, dw.Key.dn};
```

The result of this will be

[image]

Comment: Do you need help on joining provided table with your result to make it work?

Comment: In the end I did it some other way but thanks you to everyone who helped.